# UISearchBar - different tableview background for UISearchBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar

When I search on **`UISearchBar`** my normal `tableView` has set to

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath; 

{   

CustomCell *cell=(CustomCell *)[FieldTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

        //set cell background color cleare color
         cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

if (isSearching) {
    cell.AddPFFieldLable.text = [filteredContentList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];    
} else {
    cell.AddPFFieldLable.text=[[fieldArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"FName"];
}
```

[image: My Normal TableView]

but when I search anything it shows like this

[image: how to change its background color to clearcolor]

how to change it's background color to **clearColor**

Comment: also I am not able to select search fields when they appear on search display table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok I got the Answer for my query

```
[self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

only thing I am missing in my `viewDidLoad`.

Answer (score 0):

I used this code in my UISearchBar. use according to your requirement

```
-(void)addSearchController {
    // No search results controller to display the search results in the current view

    [[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn: [UISearchBar class], nil] setTintColor:CODE_2_COLOR];

    self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.placeholder = @"Search your connection list";


    UITextField *txfSearchField = [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar valueForKey:@"_searchField"];
    txfSearchField.backgroundColor = CODE_6_COLOR;
    self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.barTintColor=CODE_6_COLOR;
    CGRect rect = self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.frame;
    UIView *lineView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, rect.size.height-2,rect.size.width, 2)];
    lineView.backgroundColor = CODE_6_COLOR;
    [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar addSubview:lineView];
    [[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setDefaultTextAttributes:@{
                                                                                                 NSFontAttributeName: [FontManager getRobotoMediumFontWithSize:14],
                                                                                                 }];

    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchDisplayController.searchBar;

}
```